# Issue when expanding clojure source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, clojure, text, noweb

I have defined expand and execute functions for 'text' source blocks as follows:

```
(defun org-babel-expand-body:text (body params)
  (org-trim body))

(defun org-babel-execute:text (body params)
  (org-trim body))
```

I do this so that I can create basic templates for things like css, html, and configuration files.  I want to use clojure to manipulate the text defined in these blocks as a string.  For example, here I want to turn the output of the "sample" block into a clojure string in the "clojure-sample" block:

```
#+NAME: sample
#+begin_src text
some


text
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: sample
: some
: 
: 
: text

#+NAME: clojure-sample
#+begin_src clojure :noweb yes :results pp
"<<sample()>>"
#+end_src
```

But when I run `org-babel-expand-src-block` on the "clojure-sample" block, it expands to:

```
"some
"
"
"text"
```

Why this is not being expanded into a single string and how I might fix it?

These are the expand and execute definitions for clojure source blocks.

```
(defun org-babel-expand-body:clojure (body params)
  "Expand BODY according to PARAMS, return the expanded body."
  (let* ((vars (org-babel--get-vars params))
         (result-params (cdr (assq :result-params params)))
         (print-level nil)
         (print-length nil)
         (body
          (org-trim
           (format "%s"
                   ;; Variables binding.
                   (if (null vars) (org-trim body)
                     (format "(let [%s]\n%s)"
                             (mapconcat
                              (lambda (var)
                                (format "%S (quote %S)" (car var) (cdr var)))
                              vars
                              "\n      ")
                             body))))))
    (if (or (member "code" result-params)
            (member "pp" result-params))
        (format "(clojure.pprint/pprint (do %s))" body)
      body)))

(defun org-babel-execute:clojure (body params)
  (let ((expanded (org-babel-expand-body:clojure body params))
    (response (cons 'dict nil)))
    (let ((result-params (cdr (assoc :result-params params))))
      (setq response (nrepl-sync-request:eval expanded
                          (cider-current-connection)
                          (cider-current-ns)))
      (setq result (concat (nrepl-dict-get response
                       (if (or
                        (member "output" result-params)
                        (member "pp" result-params))
                           "out"
                         "value"))
               (nrepl-dict-get response "ex")
               (nrepl-dict-get response "root-ex")
               (nrepl-dict-get response "err")))
      (org-babel-result-cond (cdr (assoc :result-params params))
    result
    (condition-case nil (org-babel-script-excape result)
      (error result))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted to work by changing the text expand function to

```
(defun org-babel-expand-body:text (body params)
  (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote "\n") "\\n" (org-trim body) nil 'literal))
```

A clojure source block will then expand a text source block in the way where it can be interpreted as a string and can be spit to a file.